# How to fix Android MediaPlayer Auto close after screen lock

Tags: android

I have written a background service for the android mediaPlayer to run in the background, but after 3 minutes the screen is off and the music stops playing automatically.

I want to continuously play music in background.

hear is my code sample.

` mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamUrl);

```
    mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
            .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");
    wifiLock.acquire();

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to n`
```

Comment: Are you using a foreground service?  If not, you'll hit limits for background services.

Comment: @GabeSechan - No i used background service. after your answer i have conveterd it to foreground service. now its working thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and tie it with a notification otherwise the System would just kill it.

You can find an example of that using ExoPlayer [here](https://github.com/SoftwareEngineeringDaily/software-engineering-daily-android/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/koalatea/sedaily/feature/player/AudioService.kt). Notice that the service can start as a normal background service and then you can covert it to a foreground service while the player is running by calling `startForeground`. Also remember to get rid of the notification and calling `stopForeground` when the player stops otherwise that service and notification will stay there for a long time wasting memory.

The example above also takes care of Audio Focus, media button controls, lock screen controls, etc... if you are interested in addressing these issues.

Comment: Now its working Thank you very much (y)